Encountering error while trying to install opencve
I'm trying to install opencve on Linux Ubuntu, according to the documentation on their website (https://docs.opencve.io/v1/installation/manual/). On a virtual python environment, however, I keep encountering this error when running pip install opencve. Can anyone help?
muhammad@muhammad:~$ source venv-opencve/bin/activate
(venv-opencve) muhammad@muhammad:~$ pip install opencve
Collecting opencve
  Using cached opencve-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.8 kB)
Collecting Flask==1.0.2 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.2 kB)
Collecting Flask-Admin==1.5.5 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_Admin-1.5.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.9 kB)
Collecting Flask-Assets==0.12 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_Assets-0.12-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Flask-DebugToolbar==0.10.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_DebugToolbar-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
Collecting Flask-SQLAlchemy==2.3.2 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.4 kB)
Collecting Flask-Migrate==3.0.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_Migrate-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (946 bytes)
Collecting Flask-Login==0.4.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_Login-0.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Flask-WTF==0.14.3 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_WTF-0.14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.0 kB)
Collecting Flask-User==1.0.2.2 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_User-1.0.2.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Flask-Gravatar==0.5.0 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_Gravatar-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
Collecting Flask-Paginate==0.5.2 (from opencve)
  Using cached flask_paginate-0.5.2-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Flask-RESTful==0.3.8 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_RESTful-0.3.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (912 bytes)
Collecting Flask-Limiter==1.4 (from opencve)
  Using cached Flask_Limiter-1.4-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (12 kB)
Collecting SQLAlchemy==1.3.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached SQLAlchemy-1.3.1-cp312-cp312-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting SQLAlchemy-Utils==0.33.11 (from opencve)
  Using cached SQLAlchemy_Utils-0.33.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting psycopg2-binary==2.8.4 (from opencve)
  Using cached psycopg2-binary-2.8.4.tar.gz (378 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Collecting Redis==3.3.11 (from opencve)
  Using cached redis-3.3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (36 kB)
Collecting arrow==0.13.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached arrow-0.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.3 kB)
Collecting celery==4.3.0 (from opencve)
  Using cached celery-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (18 kB)
Collecting cpe==1.2.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached cpe-1.2.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting untangle==1.1.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached untangle-1.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cssmin==0.2.0 (from opencve)
  Using cached cssmin-0.2.0-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting jsmin==3.0.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached jsmin-3.0.1-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting requests==2.23.0 (from opencve)
  Using cached requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (6.8 kB)
Collecting nested-lookup==0.2.18 (from opencve)
  Using cached nested_lookup-0.2.18-py3-none-any.whl
Collecting deepdiff==4.0.7 (from opencve)
  Using cached deepdiff-4.0.7-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (19 kB)
Collecting gunicorn==20.0.4 (from opencve)
  Using cached gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting vine==1.3.0 (from opencve)
  Using cached vine-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.4 kB)
Collecting click==7.1.2 (from opencve)
  Using cached click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
Collecting werkzeug==1.0.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.7 kB)
Collecting itsdangerous==1.1.0 (from opencve)
  Using cached itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.1 kB)
Collecting markupSafe==1.1.1 (from opencve)
  Using cached MarkupSafe-1.1.1-cp312-cp312-linux_x86_64.whl
Collecting jinja2==2.11.3 (from opencve)
  Using cached Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.5 kB)
Collecting importlib-metadata==4.13.0 (from opencve)
  Using cached importlib_metadata-4.13.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.9 kB)
Collecting email-validator==1.1.0 (from opencve)
  Using cached email_validator-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (16 kB)
Collecting python-dateutil (from arrow==0.13.1->opencve)
  Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.4 kB)
Collecting pytz>dev (from celery==4.3.0->opencve)
  Using cached pytz-2024.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (22 kB)
Collecting billiard<4.0,>=3.6.0 (from celery==4.3.0->opencve)
  Using cached billiard-3.6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.5 kB)
Collecting kombu<5.0,>=4.4.0 (from celery==4.3.0->opencve)
  Using cached kombu-4.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.6 kB)
Collecting jsonpickle>=1.0 (from deepdiff==4.0.7->opencve)
  Using cached jsonpickle-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (8.2 kB)
Collecting ordered-set>=3.1 (from deepdiff==4.0.7->opencve)
  Using cached ordered_set-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
Collecting dnspython>=1.15.0 (from email-validator==1.1.0->opencve)
  Using cached dnspython-2.7.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.8 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0.0 (from email-validator==1.1.0->opencve)
  Using cached idna-3.10-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (10 kB)
Collecting wtforms (from Flask-Admin==1.5.5->opencve)
  Using cached wtforms-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.3 kB)
Collecting webassets>=0.11.1 (from Flask-Assets==0.12->opencve)
  Using cached webassets-2.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (889 bytes)
Collecting Blinker (from Flask-DebugToolbar==0.10.1->opencve)
  Using cached blinker-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.6 kB)
Collecting limits (from Flask-Limiter==1.4->opencve)
  Using cached limits-3.13.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.2 kB)
Collecting six>=1.4.1 (from Flask-Limiter==1.4->opencve)
  Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.8 kB)
Collecting alembic>=0.7 (from Flask-Migrate==3.0.1->opencve)
  Using cached alembic-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (7.4 kB)
Collecting aniso8601>=0.82 (from Flask-RESTful==0.3.8->opencve)
  Using cached aniso8601-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (23 kB)
Collecting bcrypt>=2.0 (from Flask-User==1.0.2.2->opencve)
  Downloading bcrypt-4.2.1-cp39-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (9.8 kB)
Collecting cryptography>=1.6 (from Flask-User==1.0.2.2->opencve)
  Using cached cryptography-43.0.3-cp39-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl.metadata (5.4 kB)
Collecting Flask-Mail>=0.9 (from Flask-User==1.0.2.2->opencve)
  Using cached flask_mail-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.1 kB)
Collecting passlib>=1.7 (from Flask-User==1.0.2.2->opencve)
  Using cached passlib-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.7 kB)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools>=3.0 in ./venv-opencve/lib/python3.12/site-packages (from gunicorn==20.0.4->opencve) (75.5.0)
Collecting zipp>=0.5 (from importlib-metadata==4.13.0->opencve)
  Using cached zipp-3.21.0-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.7 kB)
Collecting chardet<4,>=3.0.2 (from requests==2.23.0->opencve)
  Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting idna>=2.0.0 (from email-validator==1.1.0->opencve)
  Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (9.1 kB)
Collecting urllib3!=1.25.0,!=1.25.1,<1.26,>=1.21.1 (from requests==2.23.0->opencve)
  Using cached urllib3-1.25.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (41 kB)
Collecting certifi>=2017.4.17 (from requests==2.23.0->opencve)
  Using cached certifi-2024.8.30-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.2 kB)
Collecting Mako (from alembic>=0.7->Flask-Migrate==3.0.1->opencve)
  Using cached Mako-1.3.6-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (2.9 kB)
Collecting typing-extensions>=4 (from alembic>=0.7->Flask-Migrate==3.0.1->opencve)
  Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.0 kB)
Collecting cffi>=1.12 (from cryptography>=1.6->Flask-User==1.0.2.2->opencve)
  Using cached cffi-1.17.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (1.5 kB)
Collecting amqp<2.7,>=2.6.0 (from kombu<5.0,>=4.4.0->celery==4.3.0->opencve)
  Using cached amqp-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (1.0 kB)
Collecting deprecated>=1.2 (from limits->Flask-Limiter==1.4->opencve)
  Using cached Deprecated-1.2.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl.metadata (5.5 kB)
Collecting importlib-resources>=1.3 (from limits->Flask-Limiter==1.4->opencve)
  Using cached importlib_resources-6.4.5-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (4.0 kB)
Collecting packaging<25,>=21 (from limits->Flask-Limiter==1.4->opencve)
  Using cached packaging-24.2-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (3.2 kB)
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=1.6->Flask-User==1.0.2.2->opencve)
  Using cached pycparser-2.22-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (943 bytes)
Collecting wrapt<2,>=1.10 (from deprecated>=1.2->limits->Flask-Limiter==1.4->opencve)
  Using cached wrapt-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl.metadata (6.6 kB)
WARNING: The candidate selected for download or install is a yanked version: 'flask-user' candidate (version 1.0.2.2 at https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/10/3c/00776d0521f6269e6df65e3e0a80bfd11fff7d9d87a514a439db3c85b2bd/Flask-User-1.0.2.2.tar.gz (from https://pypi.org/simple/flask-user/) (requires-python:>=2.7, !=3.0.*, !=3.1.*, !=3.2.*, !=3.3.*))
Reason for being yanked: <none given>
Using cached opencve-1.5.0-py3-none-any.whl (1.5 MB)
Using cached arrow-0.13.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Using cached celery-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (413 kB)
Using cached click-7.1.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (82 kB)
Using cached deepdiff-4.0.7-py3-none-any.whl (47 kB)
Using cached email_validator-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (17 kB)
Using cached Flask-1.0.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (91 kB)
Using cached Flask_Admin-1.5.5-py3-none-any.whl (1.9 MB)
Using cached Flask_DebugToolbar-0.10.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (326 kB)
Using cached Flask_Gravatar-0.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (7.5 kB)
Using cached Flask_Limiter-1.4-py3-none-any.whl (15 kB)
Using cached Flask_Migrate-3.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (12 kB)
Using cached Flask_RESTful-0.3.8-py2.py3-none-any.whl (25 kB)
Using cached Flask_SQLAlchemy-2.3.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Using cached Flask_WTF-0.14.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (13 kB)
Using cached gunicorn-20.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (77 kB)
Using cached importlib_metadata-4.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (23 kB)
Using cached itsdangerous-1.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (16 kB)
Using cached Jinja2-2.11.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl (125 kB)
Using cached redis-3.3.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
Using cached requests-2.23.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Using cached vine-1.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (14 kB)
Using cached Werkzeug-1.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (298 kB)
Using cached alembic-1.14.0-py3-none-any.whl (233 kB)
Using cached aniso8601-9.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (52 kB)
Downloading bcrypt-4.2.1-cp39-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (278 kB)
   ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 278.6/278.6 kB 41.4 kB/s eta 0:00:00
Using cached billiard-3.6.4.0-py3-none-any.whl (89 kB)
Using cached certifi-2024.8.30-py3-none-any.whl (167 kB)
Using cached chardet-3.0.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (133 kB)
Using cached cryptography-43.0.3-cp39-abi3-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (4.0 MB)
Using cached dnspython-2.7.0-py3-none-any.whl (313 kB)
Using cached flask_mail-0.10.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 kB)
Using cached idna-2.10-py2.py3-none-any.whl (58 kB)
Using cached jsonpickle-4.0.0-py3-none-any.whl (46 kB)
Using cached kombu-4.6.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (184 kB)
Using cached ordered_set-4.1.0-py3-none-any.whl (7.6 kB)
Using cached passlib-1.7.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (525 kB)
Using cached pytz-2024.2-py2.py3-none-any.whl (508 kB)
Using cached six-1.16.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (11 kB)
Using cached urllib3-1.25.11-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127 kB)
Using cached webassets-2.0-py3-none-any.whl (142 kB)
Using cached zipp-3.21.0-py3-none-any.whl (9.6 kB)
Using cached blinker-1.9.0-py3-none-any.whl (8.5 kB)
Using cached limits-3.13.0-py3-none-any.whl (45 kB)
Using cached python_dateutil-2.9.0.post0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (229 kB)
Using cached wtforms-3.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (152 kB)
Using cached amqp-2.6.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (48 kB)
Using cached cffi-1.17.1-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (479 kB)
Using cached Deprecated-1.2.15-py2.py3-none-any.whl (9.9 kB)
Using cached importlib_resources-6.4.5-py3-none-any.whl (36 kB)
Using cached packaging-24.2-py3-none-any.whl (65 kB)
Using cached typing_extensions-4.12.2-py3-none-any.whl (37 kB)
Using cached Mako-1.3.6-py3-none-any.whl (78 kB)
Using cached wrapt-1.16.0-cp312-cp312-manylinux_2_5_x86_64.manylinux1_x86_64.manylinux_2_17_x86_64.manylinux2014_x86_64.whl (87 kB)
Using cached pycparser-2.22-py3-none-any.whl (117 kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: psycopg2-binary
  Building wheel for psycopg2-binary (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [66 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/_range.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/_ipaddress.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/errors.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/compat.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/pool.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/extras.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/_lru_cache.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/tz.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/extensions.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/errorcodes.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/_json.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      copying lib/sql.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg2
      running build_ext
      building 'psycopg2._psycopg' extension
      creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_asis.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_asis.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_binary.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_binary.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_datetime.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_datetime.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_list.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_list.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_pboolean.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_pboolean.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_pdecimal.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_pfloat.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_pfloat.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_pint.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_pint.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/adapter_qstring.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/adapter_qstring.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/bytes_format.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/bytes_format.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/column_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/column_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/connection_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/connection_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/connection_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/connection_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/conninfo_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/conninfo_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/cursor_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/cursor_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/cursor_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/cursor_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/diagnostics_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/diagnostics_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/error_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/error_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/green.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/green.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/libpq_support.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/libpq_support.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/lobject_int.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/lobject_int.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/lobject_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/lobject_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/microprotocols.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/microprotocols.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/microprotocols_proto.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/microprotocols_proto.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/notify_type.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/notify_type.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/pqpath.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/pqpath.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc -fno-strict-overflow -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -O2 -Wall -fPIC "-DPSYCOPG_VERSION=2.8.4 (dt dec pq3 ext lo64)" -DPG_VERSION_NUM=160004 -DHAVE_LO64=1 -I/home/muhammad/venv-opencve/include -I/usr/include/python3.12 -I. -I/usr/include/postgresql -I/usr/include/postgresql/16/server -c psycopg/psycopgmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-cpython-312/psycopg/psycopgmodule.o -Wdeclaration-after-statement
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘add_module_types’:
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:920:36: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        920 |         Py_TYPE(typetable[i].type) = &PyType_Type;
            |                                    ^
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘datetime_init’:
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:952:30: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
        952 |     Py_TYPE(&pydatetimeType) = &PyType_Type;
            |                              ^
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c: In function ‘PyInit__psycopg’:
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:1084:28: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
       1084 |     Py_TYPE(&typecastType) = &PyType_Type;
            |                            ^
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:1087:25: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
       1087 |     Py_TYPE(&chunkType) = &PyType_Type;
            |                         ^
      psycopg/psycopgmodule.c:1090:25: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
       1090 |     Py_TYPE(&errorType) = &PyType_Type;
            |                         ^
      error: command '/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for psycopg2-binary
  Running setup.py clean for psycopg2-binary
Failed to build psycopg2-binary
ERROR: Could not build wheels for psycopg2-binary, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects


I've tried everything looking on forums, can't seem to find a way to fix it. I want to setup opencve on my machine, can anyone help me out here?

The last released version of opencve is 1.5.0; it declares compatibility with Pythons 3.7 and 3.8. It requires psycopg2-binary==2.8.4 which is compatible with Python 2 and Python 3 up to 3.8.
My advice is to use Python 3.8.

It worked, thank you!
